# MySQL UDF: keep the allocated memory?

Tags: mysql, windows, memory-management, user-defined-functions

I wish to allocate memory in [xxx_init()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-udf.html) and initialize it from a large disk file.

What options do I have on Windows to avoid loading this file each time and keep the previously allocated memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pointer has to be declared as static

```
static MYTYPE *buffer = 0;
```

Then xxx_init() checks if it has been initialized. xxx_deinit() should not free the memory so it is still available for further calls to xxx()

An other function is then needed to free the memory